# How to encapsulate object fields to be in array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have an object that can be with different properties (arrays/objects/etc).

I want to convert the object to be with each sub field encapsulated by array.

For example:

```
"head": {
            "text": "Main title",
            "sub": {
                "value": "next"
            },
            "place": "secondary"
        }
```

the head field including an object.
I want the object to be encapsulate in array like this:

```
"head": [{
            "text": "Main title",
            "sub": {
                "value": "next"
            },
            "place": "secondary"
        }]
```

I figured out this is the possibility to keep the structure same for every item.

I also tryied to do so with interface but it made me problems since sometimes it's object and sometimes not so I want to keep the structure.

I would like to hear more if there's a better way to convert the object to a proper interface.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to use these structures then? Can you provide an example of usage thanks

Comment: Whatever you're up to, think of what you are trying to achieve once more. The whole operation seems quite unnatural.

Comment: Anyway, JSON is a set of (key, value) pairs, you travers though all of them, if value is not an object - you simply transform it into `[value]`, when the value is an object - repeat recursively.

Answer (score 1):

This will recursively check each value and make it an array if it isn't. Excluding keys you put in the keysToSkip array.

```
const obj = {
  "head": {
    "text": "Main title",
    "sub": {
      "value": "next"
    },
    "place": "secondary"
  },
  "alreadyArray": [
    "val", "val2"
  ]
}

const keysToSkip = ["value"]

let depthFirstLoop = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
      depthFirstLoop(obj[key]);
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[key]) && !keysToSkip.includes(key)) {
      obj[key] = [obj[key]]
    }
  });
};

depthFirstLoop(obj)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9p7k64ec/26/

Comment: Thanks! but how to do that recursively for each item?

Comment: You want each item to be in an array? If you give a starting structure and an ending structure for the object, I'd be happy to help come up with something.

Comment: Thanks again, 
How can I skip level keys that are already array and other types I don't want to wrap?

Comment: Added on a way to do both of those. You could always add more methods of skipping keys.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not running recursively for each nested object, just on the first level

Comment: Updated the answer with something new that handles all of the above recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't change an object as you iterate over it. Better to create a new object.

```
const obj = {
  "head": {
    "text": "Main title",
    "sub": {
      "value": "next"
    },
    "place": "secondary"
  }
}
var newObj = {}

for( key in obj ){
    newObj[key] = [obj[key]]
}
```

Comment: Object.keys returns an array of the keys. It's different then doing obj.forEach

Comment: No worries. I know that feelings =)